# I want to get depth data( not disparity ) from iPhone7 Plus

Tags: iphone, swift, ios11, depth, disparity-mapping

I want to get depth data( not disparity ) from iPhone7 Plus
Now, I refer to a sample source “AVCamPhotoFilter”.

And, now I can probably get disparity data.

But, I don’t know how to get depth data.

So, According to the reference about AVDepthData, 
depthDataMap is the depth data or disparity data.

If I want to get depth data,
I need to set activeDepthDataFormat or calculate using the disparity Data ?

How to set activeDepthDataFormat ?
Or 
How to calculate ?

I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, check out: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/

To calculate: Check out the video at 11:00

To get the data directly, you want to use

```
func converting(toDepthDataType depthDataType: OSType)
```

and use one of the data types at 14:20 in the video, which are:

kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat16

kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32

kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16

kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32

Edited to include data type names.